# Angular Nested Controller throwing error of not registered controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use nested controllers but I am getting an error of controller not registered. I tried to call the controller after declaring but too its not working. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
   <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="basics-controllers.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app>
  <p>
    <h2>Nested controllers with model variables defined directly on the scopes</h2>
(typing on an input field, with a data binding to the model, overrides the same variable of a parent scope)
  </p>
  <div ng-controller="firstControllerScope">
     <h3>First controller</h3>
    <strong>First name:</strong> {{$scope.firstName}}<br />
    <br />
    <label>Set the first name: <input type="text" ng-model="$scope.firstName"/></label><br />
    <br />
    <div ng-controller="secondControllerScope">
      <h3>Second controller (inside First)</h3>
      <strong>First name (from First):</strong> {{firstName}}<br />
      <strong>Last name (new variable):</strong> {{lastName}}<br />
      <strong>Full name:</strong> {{getFullName()}}<br />
      <br />
      <label>Set the first name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/></label><br />
      <label>Set the last name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/></label><br />
     <br />
   <div ng-controller="thirdControllerScope">
    <h3>Third controller (inside Second and First)</h3>
    <strong>First name (from First):</strong> {{firstName}}<br />
    <strong>Middle name (new variable):</strong> {{middleName}}<br />
    <strong>Last name (from Second):</strong> {{$parent.lastName}}<br />
    <strong>Last name (redefined in Third):</strong> {{lastName}}<br />
    <strong>Full name (redefined in Third):</strong> {{getFullName()}}<br />
    <br />
    <label>Set the first name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/></label><br />
    <label>Set the middle name: <input type="text" ng-model="middleName"/></label><br />
    <label>Set the last name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <br />
  <p>
   <h2>Nested controllers with model variables defined inside objects</h2>
(typing on an input field, with a data binding to the model, acts on a specific object without overriding variables)
  </p>
  <div ng-controller="firstControllerObj">
   <h3>First controller</h3>
   <strong>First name:</strong> {{firstModelObj.firstName}}<br />
   <br />
   <label>Set the first name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstModelObj.firstName"/></label><br />
    <br />
   <div ng-controller="secondControllerObj">
     <h3>Second controller (inside First)</h3>
         <strong>First name (from First):</strong> {{firstModelObj.firstName}}<br />
         <strong>Last name (from Second):</strong> {{secondModelObj.lastName}}<br />
         <strong>Full name:</strong> {{getFullName()}}<br />
         <br />
          <label>Set the first name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstModelObj.firstName"/></label><br />
       <label>Set the last name: <input type="text" ng-model="secondModelObj.lastName"/></label><br />
      <br />
      <div ng-controller="thirdControllerObj">
    <h3>Third controller (inside Second and First)</h3>
    <strong>First name (from First):</strong> {{firstModelObj.firstName}}<br />
    <strong>Middle name (from Third):</strong> {{thirdModelObj.middleName}}<br />
    <strong>Last name (from Second):</strong> {{secondModelObj.lastName}}<br />
    <strong>Last name (from Third):</strong> {{thirdModelObj.lastName}}<br />
    <strong>Full name (redefined in Third):</strong> {{getFullName()}}<br />
    <br />
    <label>Set the first name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstModelObj.firstName"/></label><br />
    <label>Set the middle name: <input type="text" ng-model="thirdModelObj.middleName"/></label><br />
    <label>Set the last name: <input type="text" ng-model="thirdModelObj.lastName"/></label>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS file is:

```
var firstControllerScope = function ($scope){
  // Initialize the model variables
  $scope.firstName = "John";
};
console.log('firstControllerScope',firstControllerScope("Jasdasohn"));

var secondControllerScope = function ($scope){
  // Initialize the model variables
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";
   // Define utility functions
  $scope.getFullName = function (){
    return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
  };
};

var thirdControllerScope = function ($scope){
  // Initialize the model variables
  $scope.middleName = "Al";
  $scope.lastName = "Smith";

  // Define utility functions
  $scope.getFullName = function (){
    return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.middleName + " " + $scope.lastName;
  };
};

var firstControllerObj = function ($scope){
  // Initialize the model object
  $scope.firstModelObj = {
    firstName: "John"
  };
};

var secondControllerObj = function ($scope){
  // Initialize the model object
  $scope.secondModelObj = {
    lastName: "Doe"
  };

   // Define utility functions
   $scope.getFullName = function (){
        return $scope.firstModelObj.firstName + " " +
      $scope.secondModelObj.lastName;
  };
};

var thirdControllerObj = function ($scope){
  // Initialize the model object
  $scope.thirdModelObj = {
    middleName: "Al",
    lastName: "Smith"
  };

   // Define utility functions
  $scope.getFullName = function (){
    return $scope.firstModelObj.firstName + " " +
      $scope.thirdModelObj.middleName + " " +
      $scope.thirdModelObj.lastName;
  };
};
```

I am getting this error : angular.js:14328 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=firstControllerScope

Please guide me for the appropriate usage of nested controllers.

Comment: There is no place in your code where you are registering the controllers with a module.

Comment: Ok, Yeah, that works, as I am newbie to AngularJS, I was just trying out, so the method above suggested works well. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic AngularJS.  You are not defining the Angular module neither the controllers.

`var app = angular.module('app', []);`

Here is  a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uRqN0H0UfIN0hy7HFo5j?p=preview)

Make sure to declare the module and the controllers. Also inject the module in the HTML.

I will recommend you to take a look to [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Comment: Yes, this works, as I am newbie to AngularJS, I am just trying out to get my basics strong, so the method above suggested works well. Thank you. :)